# codeigniter where to put email functions

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

Suppose I have a bunch of "email" functions- like a user signup confirmation or password recovery email, or a notifications update email. Where can I "place" these functions? My original idea was to simply keep them in the controllers, but I'd rather have a common place. Then my idea was to create a new controller specifically for emails, but that breaks the MVC pattern, and my last idea was to extend the email_helper.php helper, but if I do that, I can't do something like

`$this->email->to($email);`

because I get an error that reads

`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/elluminate/system/helpers/email_helper.php on line 71`

Comment: I have the exact same question. I'm using CI 3.10.  Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `$this` in a static method or within a simple function. The `$this` variable is only available, if you have an object.

---

In context of MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns, the mailing system itself would be considered a [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29). Services are the "upper" part of model layer, which are used by controllers and views for interaction with model layer. They help isolate the domain business logic from the presentation layer (controller, views, templates).

Services can be either independent from other model structures (like in case of mailing system), or they can be governing the interaction between [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and the different storage abstractions ([data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [units of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and/or [data access objects](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)).